# How to know the bootstrap currently installed bootstrap version?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using Bootstrap version 3.2.0 LESS files. I want to know where I can get the current version of bootstrap installed.

I know I can know it from the Nuget Package Manager but still I want to locate the file where the Version no of currently installed Bootstrap is defined.

N.B: I am using LESS source https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.2.0.zip .

Comment: Package.json will tell you the version in the root of the folder

Comment: Yes I know I can get this from Packages.config/Packages.json but what if am using LESS source and I have not installed it via NPM/node.js then?

Comment: The source zip that you linked to contains this too.  I don't know of anywhere else that contains the version number.

Comment: You can check the version of Bootstrap's jQuery plugins, e.g. `$.fn.modal.Constructor.VERSION === "3.2.0"` in Bootstrap v3.2.0